# How to obtain a list of applied Spring Boot (auto) configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to obtain a list of applied Spring Boot (auto or not) configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot Actuator is able to dump such information.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation

Enable the actuator and then open http://localhost/configprops.
Here is an example from one of my projects:

[image]

Actuator shows a lot of helpful information (autoconfig, env, mappings, beans, logfile, traces and more) so I suggest you enable it even on a production machine. It can be protected by password rather easily.

To see configuration that came from your application.properties / application.yml you can use the `/env` endpoint.

Comment: That is a very good answer considering real life scenarios. Given a prod machine in k8s cluster running for days it is obviously more effective to look up profiles in actuator.

Answer (score 8):

After you get your artifact built, you can get an auto-configuration report if you start it including the `--debug` command parameter:

```
java -jar artifact.jar --debug
```

or directly adding it as a parameter for SpringApplication.run()

```
SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class, "--debug");
```

or inside the IDE, by adding `--debug` as an argument in your launch configuration.

The report will look like this:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy,org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)
      - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration
      - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AuditAutoConfiguration#authenticationAuditListener
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AbstractAuthenticationEvent (OnClassCondition)

   AuditAutoConfiguration#authorizationAuditListener
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.access.event.AbstractAuthorizationEvent (OnClassCondition)

   AuditAutoConfiguration.AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

[...]

Negative matches:
-----------------

   ActiveMQAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory,org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnProperty missing required properties spring.aop.proxy-target-class  (OnPropertyCondition)

   AtomikosJtaConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
```

Comment: It also works not from jar, but from IDE `SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class, "--debug");`